# How do you open an HTML file with chrome, from a batch script?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

How can I open an HTML file in chrome, using a batch file?

I have tried this:

```
 start chrome index.html
```

The first part is correct, since it will open chrome, but it will just type out `index.html/` in the address bar, and since it's not a valid url it wont go anywhere

How do I open the index.html file without typing out the whole file://c:/... thingy, if I know that it's in the same directory as the batch file?

Answer (score 1):

I found it out now, just simply type out `./` before index.html

```
start chrome ./index.html
```